# Spring CrudRepository Update doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a project in spring boot and I'm using CrudRepository, but when I try to update, it doesn't do anything.

```
@Entity
public class PfmSelection implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    private Integer releaseId; 
    private String preparedBy;
}
```

Repositiry

```
@Repository
public interface IPfmSelectionDao extends CrudRepository<PfmSelection, Integer> {

}
```

Service

```
public interface IPfmSelectionService {

    public PfmSelection save(PfmSelection pfmSelection);

    public PfmSelection findById(Integer id);

}
```

Service Impl

```
@Service
public class PfmSelectionService implements IPfmSelectionService {

    @Autowired
    private IPfmSelectionDao pfmSelectionDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public PfmSelection save(PfmSelection pfmSelection) {
        return this.pfmSelectionDao.save(pfmSelection); 
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public PfmSelection findById(Integer id) {
        return this.pfmSelectionDao.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

}
```

Service where I use the other Service

```
@Autowired
    private IPfmSelectionService pfmSelectionService;

private void updatePfm(PushModel pushModel) {
    PfmSelection pfm = this.pfmSelectionService.findById(167427);
    
     pfm.setPreparedBy("Rodrige");
     pfmSelectionService.save(pfm);

}
```

I don't receive any error in the console.

[image]

Comment: Need to see your dao + error msg. This looks off

Comment: It's at least not good to do the read and the update in different Transactions.
Try to remove the Annotations in the Service and put int on `updatePfm`

Comment: Sorry @Llama I dont receive any error

Comment: @jonathangonzalez, so how do you know it doesn't do anything? How do you check that? Can you show _that_ code too?

Comment: there should be if something is failing so you need to look more carefully. Additionally, your save method is built into your @Repository you shouldnt need to create a new save method in your service. You need to look at a tutorial bc your architecture is way off

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev, I know it because in the database the record is not modified.

Comment: @Llama I am using another service for saving because they are 2 different services and each one has its own business rules, right now you see it with nothing because there are still several more functionalities to implement.

Comment: I just add a screenshot of my console, how you can see I dont receive an error, I just receive the last select that it made with the findById. the strange thing is that when I create a new instance, if it does an insert, only the update is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried marking the updatePfm method as transactional? I seem to recall calling something with Transactional(readOnly = true) will start a transaction that may continue on your pfmSelectionService. if the entity exists, it will be 'managed' by the context likely being reused by the later save call. Read-only isn't a great option IMO in spring except where absolutely necessary for performance. Try it - if changing the transaction demarcation points works, we can help find a solution that better fits your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a few steps to know what the problem is

1. Take the return of pfmSelectionService.save(pfm) and print the saved instance returned like below:

   ```
   private void updatePfm(PushModel pushModel) {
       PfmSelection pfm = this.pfmSelectionService.findById(167427);
       pfm.setPreparedBy("Rodrige");
       PfmSelection pfm2 = pfmSelectionService.save(pfm);
       System.out.println(pfm2.getPreparedBy());
   }
   ```
2. Put logger/debugger inside the save method, before and after the save method and check for the entry/exit sop/logger statements in log/console like

   ```
   @Override
   @Transactional
   public PfmSelection save(PfmSelection pfmSelection) {
        System.out.println("Inside save method");
        PfmSelection pfmSelectionSaved = 
                          this.pfmSelectionDao.save(pfmSelection);
        System.out.println("Exits save method");
        return pfmSelectionSaved; 
   }
   ```
3. Check for any Aop around advice or any place where the exception is being caught but eaten/not thrown further.
4. Check if there is any update query fired in the logs at the time of save call.
5. Also check if the setter method `pfm.setPreparedBy("Rodrige");` is Empty?

Comment: You're suggesting checking if ```getPreparedBy``` changed AFTRE the ```save``` operation. The OP should really check the ```pfm``` data was updated after the ```setPreparedBy``` which is the only statement he used to changed the model, but BEFORE the ```save```. If his model is unchanged after, then a *subsequent* call to ```save``` will not persist anything because the data is unchanged. Your answer suggests the ```save``` method itself fails or an exception is thrown but consumed somewhere, yet the OP showed he has no exceptions and it does nothing, which is expected if the data is unchanged

Comment: I have done what Yogesh says and I got the 3 messages "Inside save method".
"Exits save method"
"Rodrige". In the logs there is no any update query, Just the last query in the findById that it was a select.

Comment: @majixin Hi, I asked him to check the setter method if that is playing any tricks, second ther are sometimes cases that the exception was thrown but caught and eaten somewhere which was never logged so to negate that possibility i asked him to check and additionally put a logger/sop in the save method after the save call.

Comment: @jonathangonzalez it looks like that hibernate is noting the changes but not flushing (or allow them to be flushed) them to db, can you once try removing (readOnly = true) from the findById method, though it is a try only to see if things work.

Comment: Hi guys, I have been able to solve the problem and it is that there was another method that was invoking the update and this one had @Transactional readonly, I have removed the readonly and everything is fine now.

Comment: Hi @jonathangonzalez, glad to hear that your problem is solved.